# In java How to access a List (ArrayList of emails) inside an array of objects returned as a Rest response to a @GETMapping API

Tags: java, rest, aws-lambda

I am hitting GET API and in response I am getting an array of objects in which every object has a list (ArrayList of emails). I can access ALL the values of the object except the List of emails. I have tried with list, Array, String, etc... but I am not able to access the email Addresses from the List inside the Object.

** Please show me how I can access the List of emails?

I printed attributeID and it prints attributeId for all the objects, but I cannot access the List of emails through my java code. If I try, it gives me NullPointerException.

## Output:

Email List Size: 0
Email List Size: 0
Email List Size: 0
Email List Size: 0

I am able to get the entire List of objects, including the List of emails inside the objects, using Postman.

## Postman output (localhost:8080/ann/app):

```
[
{
    "attributeId": 12345,
    "attributeTitle": "Hello World",
    "someNumber": null,
    "totalAmount": 20,
    "emailList": [
        "emp1725@xxmail.com",
        "emp3399@xxmail.com",
        "emp9125@xxmail.com",
        "emp9978@xxmail.com",
    ]
},
{
    "attributeId": 23456,
    "attributeTitle": "Hello America",
    "someNumber": null,
    "totalAmount": 30,
    "emailList": [
        "dmp1725@xxmail.com",
        "dmp3399@xxmail.com",
        "dmp9125@xxmail.com",
        "dmp9978@xxmail.com",
    ]
},
{
    "attributeId": 34567,
    "attributeTitle": "Hello Texas",
    "someNumber": null,
    "totalAmount": 40,
    "emailList": [
        "bng1725@xxmail.com",
        "bng3399@xxmail.com",
        "bng9125@xxmail.com",
        "bng9978@xxmail.com",
    ]
},
{
    "attributeId": 45678,
    "attributeTitle": "Hello California",
    "someNumber": null,
    "totalAmount": 50,
    "emailList": [
        "wtm1725@xxmail.com",
        "wtm3399@xxmail.com",
        "wtm9125@xxmail.com",
        "wtm9978@xxmail.com",
    ]
}
```

]

```
enter code here
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CmsObject {
    private String attributeId;
    private String attributeTitle;
    private String someNumber;
    private int totalAmount;
    private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

   //Getters & Settors.... (Used Eclipse to Generate)
}

@Component
public class CmsNotiHandler {
    public void handler() {
        String restURL = System.getenv("nRestUrl");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CmsObject>> listOffrn = new 
        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CmsObject>>() {
        };

    ResponseEntity<List<CmsObject>> cmsResponse
            = restTemplate.exchange(restURL, HttpMethod.GET, new 
    HttpEntity<>(getHeaders()), listOffrn);
    List<CmsObject> cmsList = cmsResponse.getBody();

    for (CmsObject cc : cmsList) { 
        System.out.println("Email List Size: " + cc.getEmails().size());
    }
}
private static HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
    String restServiceUsername = System.getenv("username");
    String restServicePassword = System.getenv("password");
    StringBuilder plainCredentials = new StringBuilder();
    plainCredentials.append(restServiceUsername).append(":")
        .append(restServicePassword);
    String base64Credentials = new 
    String(Base64Utils.encode(plainCredentials.toString()
        .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + base64Credentials);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return headers;
}
```

}

Comment: Well, the JSON uses `emailList` as the name of the property. The Java class uses `emails`. To you, it's the same thing. Not to a dumb computer. Also, the fields should be of type `List<String>`, not `ArrayList<String>`. Program to interfaces.

Comment: I tried using List<String

Comment: I tried using       private List<String> emails;      then i created the objects as shown and tried accessing through CmsObject co : cmsList and then print co.getEmails() It throws NullPointerException. If I try co.getEmails.size() it prints 0.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CmsObject Class to match the JSON you are getting

```
public class CmsObject {
    private String attributeId;
    private String attributeTitle;
    private String someNumber;
    private int totalAmount;
    private ArrayList<String> emailList= new ArrayList<>();

   //Getters & Settors.... (Used Eclipse to Generate)
   //change getter & settor for emailList
}
```

If you cant change the name of the email in your POJO,you can us `@JsonProperty` Annotation

```
public class CmsObject {
        private String attributeId;
        private String attributeTitle;
        private String someNumber;
        private int totalAmount;
        @JsonProperty("emailList")
        private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();

       //Getters & Settors.... (Used Eclipse to Generate)
    }
```

Comment: As per your advice I decorated with @JsonProperty("emailList") IT WORKS!!! Thank you a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where you're actually doing the serialization from the json to the object, but I did notice that in your object declaration, you are initializing an empty list `private ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();`
. If you are actually able to access the list after you serialize, but it's empty, maybe it's because you've declared it as empty, and try just not declaring it?

Comment: I have tried using private List<String> emails, also. If I then print the size() it is 0 for all the List of emails in all the cmsObjects.

Comment: I am able to print all the values of the cmsObject except the List of emails.